# How to successfully self-host a ASP.NET MVC app or OData service for a workstation app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, wcf-data-services

Is it possible to self-host an ASP.NET MVC application and/or OData service in a stand-alone workstation app?  Are there any successful examples of doing this?

I would like to create a suite of data-centric applications using .NET that are targeted to EITHER a solo/home user OR a team.  Unfortunately, I am the only developer.  Comparing front-end technologies of WinForms, WPF, and ASP.NET MVC, I am most proficient with ASP.NET MVC.  I would also not like to write multiple implementations of my data service.

Comment: Have you looked at the [NancyFx](http://nancyfx.org/) framework? You can host it easily inside IIS or self host. Examples of both are available in the [docs](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Documentation).

Comment: Plex Media server has a similar strategy - of having the core functionality in a standalone executable but then exposing the UI elements through a web browser. Thought I have no idea about the actual technology used to create that. I've used their final product in that way and like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Commenting in lieu of voting down as my profile cannot yet vote down.)

You really need to do some research here.  Almost any service-oriented .NET technology can be self-hosted... WCF web services, OData, etc.  Your bigger concern should be performance.  The more layers you add to your app, and the more times you transform or "serve" your data, the more cycles will be spent processing your data.  What you may find is that you users become less happy with the performance compared to a snappy compiled UI hitting a simple business or data layer.

In short, yes, this is possible.  However, I would save this type of app for one-off / in-a-pinch apps with either a short life expectancy or very minimal client usage (settings panel, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for commenting instead of removing the question.  I was looking for guidance and opinion and not simply source code.

Comment: I really wouldn't have thought CPU performance would the biggest issue here. Web hosting is simply not the right technology for a standalone app. Sure you make it do it, but should you? No is the answer if you weren't sure.